# Overriding multiplication operator for different datatypes

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I created the following class

```
template<typename T, typename S>
class Polar{

private:
  T rad;
  S phi;

public:
  Polar(T r, S p) : rad{r}, phi{p} {}
  template<typename A, typename B> 
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polar<A,B>&);
```

And i want to override the multiplication function for different datatypes for example int and double like this

```
int main() {
   Polar<int,int> p{2,3};
   Polar<int,int> w{4,5};
   Polar<float,double> z{6,7};

   std::cout << p*w << std::endl;
   std::cout << p*z << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I declared the function as a friend in Polar like this:

```
 template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D> 
 friend auto operator*(const Polar<A,B>&, const Polar<C,D>&);
```

And then implemented it as the following:

```
 template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
 auto operator*(const Polar<A,B>& p, const Polar<C,D>& w) -> Polar<decltype(p.rad * w.rad),decltype(p.phi + w.phi)>
 {
   return Polar<decltype(p.rad * w.rad),decltype(p.phi + w.phi)> {(p.rad * w.rad),(p.phi + w.phi)};  
 }
```

But i am getting an error because of using auto before deduction.
I dont know how to get the return-type to work and i dont want to write a function for each possible combination.

Is there an easy way to tackle this?

Comment: did you ask yourself what should be the returned type of `operator*` ?

Comment: It should return a new Polar class with the result of the multiplication. But with a typecast if necessary for example int * double should return a double but int * int should only return int

Comment: have you tried replacing `auto` by `Polar<decltype(A * C),decltype(C + D)>` ?

Comment: Yes but it only caused a lot of errors (expected primary-expression before token * )

Comment: You may want to use [common_type_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) here, in order to decide the output types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::common_type_t>` may serve here. It gives you ["the common type among all types T..., that is the type all T... can be implicitly converted to."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/aeq5Tcrbr)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>  // common_type_t

template<typename T, typename S>
class Polar
{
public:
    Polar(T r, S p) : rad{r}, phi{p} {}

    template<typename A, typename B> 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polar<A, B>&);
    
    template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
    friend auto operator*(const Polar<A, B>& p, const Polar<C, D>& w);
private:
    T rad;
    S phi;
};

template<typename A, typename B> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Polar<A, B>& p)
{
    return os << "(" << p.rad << ", " << p.phi << ")";
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
auto operator*(const Polar<A, B>& p, const Polar<C, D>& w)
{
    using RT = std::common_type_t<A, C>;
    using RS = std::common_type_t<B, D>;
    
    return Polar<RT, RS>{p.rad * w.rad, p.phi + w.phi};
}

int main()
{
   Polar<int, int> p{2, 3};
   Polar<int, int> w{4, 5};
   Polar<float, double> z{6.5, 7.5};

   std::cout << p* w << std::endl;
   std::cout << p*z << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note: As usual, for integral types smaller than `int`, `std::common_type_t<A, A>` is `A` whereas `decltype(A() * A())` would be `int`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! That would make `decltype(A() * A())` a better option to avoid possible overflows, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just for types smaller than `int`, so not in general case.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got it i only needed to change the declartion in class from

```
 template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D> 
 friend auto operator*(const Polar<A,B>&, const Polar<C,D>&);
```

To the following:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D> 
friend auto operator*(const Polar<A,B>& p, const Polar<C,D>& w) -> Polar<decltype(p.rad * w.rad),decltype(p.phi + w.phi)>;
```

Comment: It's a bit more wordy, but it should work. The body of the function gets leaner this way: https://godbolt.org/z/44z57PG4o